# How do you make an async request to firebase `once` using redux observable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, redux-observable

This is my epic that isn't working.

```
export const getUserDetails = (action$) =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType(GET_USER_DATA),
        mergeMap(async (action) => {
            const readData = firebaseApp.database().ref(`users/${id}`)
            const myData = await readData.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.val()
                // console.log(data) this works correctly
                return data
            })
            return [fetchDataFulfilled(myData)]
        }),
        catchError((e) =>
            of({
                type: 'FAILED_TO_FETCH_DATA',
                e,
            }),
        ),
    )
```

when I log the data inside the await, it is there. but for some reason I can't pass it on to the action to fulfill it

error is saying: `Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

but this is middleware?

so my main question is, how do I wait for firebase to fulfil and then send data to my epic correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to convert Promise to observable with `rxjs` [from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) operator

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs';
const fetchUserFulfilled = payload => ({ type: `FETCH_USER_FULFILLED`, payload });
const failedFetch = error => ({type: 'FAILED_TO_FETCH_DATA', error});

const getData = (id) => from(firebaseApp.database()
  .ref(`users/${id}`).
  .once('value')
  .then((snapshot) => snapshot.val()))

export const getUserDetails = (action$) =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType(GET_USER_DATA),
        mergeMap((action) => getData(id)),
        map(fetchUserFulfilled)
        catchError((error) => of(failedFetch(error)))
    )
```

Comment: ahh nice. almost perfect. just one other question. the data I get back from `snapshot.val()` needs an extra level of converting. where can I do this? ie. convert from obj of objs to arrays of objects

Comment: figured I would stick it in the `.then` part of `getData`

Comment: do you know how I would dispatch 2 functions in this example? as in `fetchUserFulfilled` and `anotherOne`

Comment: You have to create new observable with those two functions and stuff it with `mergeMap` `.mergeMap(data => of(fetchUserFulfilled(data), anotherOne()))`.

Comment: hi Józef, just picking this up again now. do you think you would be able to answer if I post another question about it? just wondering if the new code is too long for comments

Comment: I think its better to make a new question about it.

Comment: will do now. please take a look if you get a chance. would really appreciate it!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62391509/you-provided-undefined-where-a-stream-was-expected-in-redux-observable here is the q if you get a second mate