# You provided `undefined` where a stream was expected in Redux Observable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, redux-observable

Trying to wrap my head around RxJS and redux observable

I have this:

```
export const getSomeData = (action$) =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType(GET_USER_DATA),
        mergeMap((action) => getData(action.id)),
        map(fetchUserFulfilled),
        catchError((e) =>
            of({
                type: 'FAILED_TO_FETCH_DATA',
                e,
            }),
        ),
    )
```

which works good, but now I want to actually fire 2 observables when I get the data back so I tried this:

```
export const getSomeData = (action$) =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType(GET_USER_DATA),
        mergeMap((action) => getData(action.id)),
        mergeMap((data) => {
            const newData = data.somethingelse
            of(fetchUserFulfilled(newData), anotherOne(newData))
        }),

        catchError((e) =>
            of({
                type: 'FAILED_TO_FETCH_DATA',
                e,
            }),
        ),
    )
```

but this is failing. so how can I fix this and what misunderstanding am I having and how should I use `mergeMap` properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mergeMap` should return an observable

```js
mergeMap((data) => {
            const newData = data.somethingelse
            return of(fetchUserFulfilled(newData), anotherOne(newData))
        }),
```

Comment: ah so it's almost right, just not "returning" anything ?

Comment: If you don't specify return value it defaults to `undefined`, now i don't know how internally that thing is handled